# AWS Lightsail Wordpress Version control

Tags: wordpress, git, amazon-web-services, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

I'm working on a wordpress site hosted on an AWS Lightsail instance (Bitnami) and i'd like to have version control to work on our site themes with a coworker.

I like the idea of just having to `git pull` to make changes to the site.
In the wordpress folder (that contains wp-admin, licences, wp-config.php, etc...), there is the wp-content folder but it's a symbolic link that points outside the wordpress folder to `root/bitnami/wordpress/wp-content`. I can't use git in the wordpress folder but I can set it up in the `root/bitnami/wordpress/wp-content` but it feels like bad practice since it asks me for admin privileges for every command line.

Is there a reason the wp-content folder is a symbolic link that points to outside the wordpress folder or is it just a mistake from the person who set things up?
Is it okay to use git to bypass an ftp client in this case?

Answer (score 0):

So I just had this same issue today, and I resolved this by moving the directories for .../wp-content to the location of the symlinks and deleting the symlinks.

This was my process (though you could delete the symlinks first):

1. Move wp-content `mv /bitnami/wordpress/wp-content /location/of/wordpress/temporary-directory-name`
2. Delete symlinks `rm -f /location/of/wordpress/`
3. Rename temporary-directory-name using move `mv /location/of/wordpress/temporary-directory-name /location/of/wordpress/wp-content`

You can then repeat the same steps for the wp-config.php file. Once this was done I was able to verify Wordpress was still working on my LightSail instance. Hope this helps

Comment: Okay I'll try this and give an update. Thank you.